# Números autodivisibles

Tags: c++

Bueno soy principiante en la programación y necesito ayuda con un código,el enunciado es el siguiente: Se dice que un número es autodivisible si cada uno de sus dígitos divide exactamente el número formado por todos los dígitos hasta el dígito en cuestión. Veamos algunos ejemplos: 1. El número 213 es autodivisible porque 2 se divide a sí mismo, 1 divide a 21, y 3 divide a 213. quiero escribir un programa que solicite ingresar un número natural (entero positivo) y retorne si el número ingresado es autodivisible o no.

Un saludo
el codigo, aqui tengo problemas cuando un numero lleva 0

```
#include <stdio.h>

int div2, numero, a, b, c, ab, div;

int main()
{
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero positivo de tres digitos: \n");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    a = numero/100;

    b = (numero%100)/10;

    c = numero%10;

    ab = a*10+b;

    div = ab%b;

    div2 = numero%c;



    if(numero>=1 && numero < 1000) {
        if(div == 0 && div2 == 0) {
            printf("\n El numero %d es autodivisible", numero);
        } else {
            printf("\n El numero %d no es autodivisible", numero);
        }
    } else {
        printf("El numero ingresado no es un entero positivo o no esta en el rango de tres digitos");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Cuando el numero es cero, obviamente te da error en division por 0. En esos casos, que queres hacer?

Comment: 0 es divisor de algun numero? :D

Comment: ¿Seguro que la pregunta es sobre [tag:c++]?

Comment: Esto es código C... que sea compatible con C++ no implica que sea C++

Comment: al 0 me refiero con un numero que contenga 0, como 703; ahi me arroja un error. lo que quiero hacer es cuando el numero que ingresa sea autodivisible me lo imprima en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Para este ejercicio hay que tener en cuenta que:

- El rango de trabajo es de 3 cifras.
- Números entre 1 y 999.
- 0/0 es matemáticamente es indefinido, por lo que ingresar solo el 0 queda indefinido y a la derecha de cualquier número también queda indefinido.

Yo lo resolví y lo pensé de esta manera:
La variable que ingreso es de tipo string así separo cada cifra. Primero se verifica que lo ingresado este dentro del rango de trabajo.

- Si es de una cifra es autodivisible.
- si es de dos cifras, primero vemos que la cifra de la derecha sea distinto de cero para que no sea indefinida la operación. Luego analizamos si el residuo de la division de la cifra total sobre la segunda cifra sea igual a cero. Si se cumple esto sería autodivisible.
- Para un número de tres cifras seria igual, vemos que los números de la derecha no sean cero. luego dividimos las cifras en Auxiliar y Auxiliar1 para tener los residuos, si estos son ceros, el número sería autodivisible.

Dejo el código abajo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;



int main(){
    string numero, a,b,c;
    int auxiliar, auxiliar1;
    cout<<("Ingrese un numero entero positivo de tres digitos: \n");
    cin >> numero;
    if (atoi(numero.c_str())>=1 && atoi(numero.c_str())<=999)
    {
        cout << "entra en el rango" << endl;

        if (numero.length()==1)
        {
            cout << "Es autodivisible" << endl;

        }

        if (numero.length()==2)
        {
            b=numero[1];
            if (atoi(b.c_str())!=0)
            {
                auxiliar=atoi(numero.c_str())%atoi(b.c_str());
                if (auxiliar==0)
                {

                    cout << "Número autodivisible" << endl;                 
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Número no autodivisible" << endl;
                    cout << "Residuo: " << auxiliar;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No es autodivisible" << endl;
            }           
        }

        if (numero.length()==3)
        {
            a=numero[0]+numero[1];;
            b=numero[1];
            c=numero[2];

            auxiliar=atoi(a.c_str())%atoi(b.c_str());
            auxiliar1=atoi(numero.c_str())%atoi(c.c_str());

            if (atoi(b.c_str())!=0 && atoi(c.c_str())!=0)
            {
                    if (auxiliar==0 && auxiliar1==0)
                    {
                        cout << "Número autodivisible" << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Número no autodivisible" << endl;
                        cout << "Residuo: " << auxiliar;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No es autodivisible" << endl;
            }

        }


    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Número fuera del requerimiento";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A diferencia de [@HernanL.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169515/463), creo que usar cadenas en este caso complica demasiado el código:

```
int main()
{
  int numero = 0;
  bool autodivisible = true;

  for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
  {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    int digito = c - '0';
    numero = numero * 10 + digito;

    autodivisible &= ( digito != 0 ) && ( numero % digito == 0);
  }

  std::cout << "El numero " << numero;
  if( autodivisible )
    std::cout << " es autodivisible\n";
  else
    std::cout << " no es autodivisible\n";

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```